# How to run method db.rawExecSQL in android SQLite?

Tags: android

I am new in android database.
I tried to run db.rawExecSQL, but I couldn't do it.

How can i use this method?

this is my simple code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
db.rawExecSQL("DETACH DATABASE encrypted;");
```

this is picture of error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYoxI.png)

please help me.

Comment: There is no `rawExecSQL()` method [on `SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). Use `execSQL()`.

Comment: The available methods can be found at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html . You can use db.execSQL for same.